# Showing Data in a specific format inside asp repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a repeater control which have my data retrieved from database. I need to show them in the following format in the HTML.

```html
<ul>
  <li>
     <div>content 1</div>
     <div>content 2</div>
     <div>content 3</div>
     <div>content 4</div>
  </li>
  <li> 
     <div>content 5</div>
     <div>content 6</div>
     <div>content 7</div>
     <div>content 8</div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

I need to put a li tag for each 4 items that are bound from the repeater.
if any of you guys know how to achieve this, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Below Code-** [Data-Binding Expressions - Eval()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366(v=vs.140).aspx)

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">         
<HeaderTemplate>
          <ul>
      </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>

      <li>
         <div><%# Eval("content1") %></div> // content1 is DB Column Name 
         <div><%# Eval("content2") %></div> // content2 is DB Column Name 
         <div><%# Eval("content3") %></div> // as so on for all content... till 8
         <div><%# Eval("content4") %></div>
      </li>
      <li> 
         <div><%# Eval("content5") %></div>
         <div><%# Eval("content6") %></div>
         <div><%# Eval("content7") %></div>
         <div><%# Eval("content8") %></div>
      </li>


    </ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
          </ul>
      </FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: What I meant by content 1, content 2 and so on was, different data items.

Comment: content1,content2..till 8 comes from DB . m I right?

Comment: I think you didnt get my question.
it looks like this inside the div 
<asp:image> where I bind a image 
<asp:hyperlink> where I bind a URL 
<asp:lable> where I bind a description 

Which are retrieved from the database.